# Problemas con la validación de instanceof

Tags: javascript, class, prototipos

Gente estoy teniendo problemas al generar un objeto a partir de mi clase Computador, yo tengo una Clase que genera un procesador y quería validar si es instancia de ella pero al ejecutar el código no validad la condicional y me deja ingresarlo normal

```js
function Procesador(marca, modelo){
  this.marca = marca;
  this.modelo = modelo;
}



function Computador({
  procesador = "",
  placa = "",
  disco = "",
  tarjetaGraf = ""
}){
  this.placa = placa;
  this.disco = disco;
  this.tarjetaGraf = tarjetaGraf;

  if(!procesador instanceof Procesador){
    console.error(`${procesador} no es una instancia de "Procesador"`);
   
  }else{
    this.procesador = procesador
  }
}
```

Aquí le paso un objeto literal y no debería de poder asignarlo porque no es una instancia de una clase
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Que tal si usas paréntesis `!(procesador instanceof Procesador)`. Por cierto la lógica negativa es más difícil de leer, te recomiendo invertir las condiciones para no tener que usar `!`. De cualquier forma, debe funcionar con paréntesis.

Comment: Graciasssss, si con eso basto, tenia rato atrapado aquí. Muchas gracias!

Comment: El problema es que el operador ! se aplica antes de ejecutar instanceof. Al aplicar ! conviertes el objeto a booleano, y un booleano nunca será una instancia de Procesador.